# AutoCAD Vault Connectivity c#

Tags: c#, properties, autocad, autodesk-vault

I had created a project to access the properties of SheetSet and as well as AutoCAD Vault functionalites including Checkin to Server, CheckOut  from server and all. It was developed using C# based on AutoCAD 2012 .dll files. And tested using AutoDesk Vault 2012 server. It worked fine, But the same code, i.e the same .exe file is not working with AutoDesk Vault 2015 server. Even the log In into the server is not happening.
But normal accessing of SheetSet properties is working good, without any problem.
 
Now, It keepon saying as credentials problems., I'm pretty sure it's not the actual problem.

**My Question is:**
1. "Is the code differs based on the AutoCAD version..?".
2. "If it is, Is there any possibility to write code once, and access for all kinds of versions..?".

Please do the needful, any help would be appreciateable., Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Vault 2012 clients are not compatible with Vault 2015 server (http://justonesandzeros.typepad.com/blog/2014/03/whats-new-in-the-vault-2015-sdk.html).

You have to change references, update some portions of code, update the .NET framework version (4.5 for Vault 2015) and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my answer. 
From AutoDesk 2013 product, they are following new kind of pattern. 
So older version before 2012 are not compatible. But newer versions from 2013 to 2015, it supports compatibility (using a set of 5 or 6 dll files).